# How to get rid of solutions with -0.0 in SBV

Tags: haskell, smt

The following code (using SBV):

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import Data.SBV
main :: IO ()
main = do
    res <- allSat zeros
    putStrLn $ show res

zeros :: Predicate
zeros = do
    z1 <- sDouble "Z1"
    constrain $ z1 .== 0.0
    return true
```

generates two solutions:

```
Solution #1:
  Z1 = 0.0 :: SDouble
Solution #2:
  Z1 = -0.0 :: SDouble
Found 2 different solutions.
```

How do I eliminate the uninteresting `-0.0` solution? I cannot use `z1 ./= -0.0` because it is also true when `z1` is `0.0`.

Comment: To recognize x=-0 you can do  x==0 && (1/x)<0

Comment: Good question.  My first reaction was `signum (-0.0)` (nope, returns zero) and `isNegativeZero` (nope, no instance for `SDouble`).

Comment: As @augustss said, translated in to SBV: `(x .== 0) &&& ((1 / x) .< 0)`

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the ` (1/x)<0` makes solving terribly slow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Updated after SBV 4.4 release on Hackage (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv), which provides proper support.]

Assuming you have SBV >= 4.4, you can now do:

```
Prelude Data.SBV> allSat $ \z -> z .== (0::SDouble)
Solution #1:
  s0 = 0.0 :: Double
Solution #2:
  s0 = -0.0 :: Double
Found 2 different solutions.
Prelude Data.SBV> allSat $ \z -> z .== (0::SDouble) &&& bnot (isNegativeZeroFP z)
Solution #1:
  s0 = 0.0 :: Double
This is the only solution.
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, the following code produces only a single solution:

```
zeros :: Predicate
zeros = do
    z1 <- sDouble "Z1"
    constrain $ z1 .== 0.0 &&& ((1 / z1) .> 0)
    return true
```

Output:

```
Solution #1:
  Z1 = 0.0 :: SDouble
This is the only solution.
```

Comment: SBV has a few recognizers for floating-point: isFPPoint (recognizes point floats, i.e., no NaNs or Infinities), isSNaN (which recognizes NaNs), and we can definitely add isSNegativeZero/isSPositiveZero etc. to the mix. In the mean time, the above solution is adequate, but it's actually costly since it involves arithmetic and comparisons for this trivial test that the underlying solver can implement much more efficiently. Feel free to submit a ticket at the SBV github page and I'll add it in the next release (https://github.com/LeventErkok/sbv/issues).

Comment: Yes, it is actually very costly. I created the following function for defining probabilities:

`probability :: String -> Symbolic SDouble`

`probability varName = do { x <- sDouble varName; constrain $ x .>= 0.0 &&& x .<= 1 &&& ((1 / x) .> 0); return x }`

And even  trivial model takes much longer then without the `&&& ((1 / x) .> 0)` part. Is there anything we could use in SMT-Lib directly?

Comment: I might be sufficient to add a test `isPositive :: SDouble -> SBool` as [`(fp.isPositive (_ FloatingPoint eb sb) Bool)`](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories/FloatingPoint.smt2).

Comment: Why would you add this as a constraint if it slows down solving so badly?  Just filter out the undesired result until someone patches SBV with an efficient method.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson is making a good point: A good alternative is to extract results and discard the ones on the Haskell side. Of course, having the predicates available is the better choice. One goal of SBV is to make everything available to the user so arbitrary programs can be written to construct problems and process output models, so I'd like to know if you try that and have any issues.